# TypeError: item.name.toLowerCase(...).include is not a function reactjs

Tags: reactjs

hello iam new with this reactjs, iam currently try some course at Egghead and when i try this [topic](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-map-to-create-react-components-from-arrays-of-data) about Use map to Create React Components from Arrays of Data
i get some error , i dont understand cause i already have same code

```
import React from 'react'

class  Filter extends React.Component{
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        items : [],
        filter :""
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(({results: items})=>
          this.setState({items})  
    )
}

filter(event){
    this.setState({filter: event.target.value})
}

render(){
    let items = this.state.items
    console.log(items)
    if(this.state.filter){
        items = items.filter( item => 
        item.name.toLowerCase()
        .include(this.state.filter.toLowerCase()))
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.filter}
            <input type="text" onChange={this.filter.bind(this)}/>
            {items.map(item => <Org key={item.name} org={item}/>)}
        </div>
    )

}

    }
    const Org = (props) => <h4 >{props.org.name}</h4>

    export default Filter
```

this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsHht.png) show when i try filter it , its like i cant call array items with key name , that array get from api

Comment: It's `includes`, not `include`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). You made a little typo

```
item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.filter.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check if the item is of type `string` in case it's not.

Something like:

`if (item && typeof item === "string") item.name.toLowerCase();`

Because there's always a possibility that your array might be populated with elements other than of type `string`.

Comment: In conjunction to what @Treycos has said.